# numpy.asarray: how to check up that its result dtype is numeric?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types

I have to create a `numpy.ndarray` from array-like data with int, float or complex numbers.

I hope to do it with `numpy.asarray` function.

I don't want to give it a strict `dtype` argument, because I want to convert complex values to `complex64` or `complex128`, floats to `float32` or `float64`, etc.

But if I just simply run `numpy.ndarray(some_unknown_data)` and look at the dtype of its result, how can I understand, that the data is numeric, not object or string or something else?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You could check if the dtype of the array is a sub-dtype of `np.number`. For example:

```
>>> np.issubdtype(np.complex128, np.number)
True
>>> np.issubdtype(np.int32, np.number)
True
>>> np.issubdtype(np.str_, np.number)
False
>>> np.issubdtype('O', np.number) # 'O' is object
False
```

Essentially, this just checks whether the dtype is below 'number' in the [NumPy dtype hierarchy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html):

[image]