# List of all possible data types returned by pandas.DataFrame.dtypes

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know the list of all possible data types returned by pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.

(A) As per https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html the following are all the possible data types in pandas:

object, int64, float64, bool, datetime64, timedelta, category

(B) [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245848/what-are-all-the-dtypes-that-pandas-recognizes) talks about pandas supporting many more kinds of data types including PeriodDType, CategoricalDtype, etc.

Is it correct to say that (A) represents all possible data types with 'object' doing the heavy lifting for all the additional datatypes not specified (i.e., including for those in (B))?

Comment: `A` is just outdated. The SO answer in `B` discusses new pandas 1.0.0 dtypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#dtypes

This should give you the info required. TL-DR; pandas generally supports these numpy dtypes - `float, int, bool, timedelta64[ns], datetime64[ns]`  in addition to the generic `object` dtype which is a catchall.

However, pandas has been introducing extension dtypes for a while now.

> Is it correct to say that (A) represents all possible data types with 'object' doing the heavy lifting for all the additional datatypes not specified (i.e., including for those in (B))?

No, `object` is primarily there for either string columns or columns with mixed types. The newer ExtensionDtypes seem to be similar to `np.dtypes`

> A pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionDtype is similar to a numpy.dtype object. It describes the data type.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#extending-extension-types

Comment: Thanks. Clarification: Is int64/float64 the correct format or int/float? The exact format is important for me as I will be building a dictionary with keys=dtype

Comment: those would be numpy dtypes - this answer probably best explains it. ints can be 
signed/unsigned etc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518923/numpy-asarray-how-to-check-up-that-its-result-dtype-is-numeric